# What is the fastest way to factor polynomials algebraically?

Tags: polynomials

What is the fastest way that you can do by hand? For example: (just a simple example, the answer should be general of course)

$x^4 -4x^3 +8x$

or

$2x^2+3x+1$

Comment: First, you have to tell us in which field you want the factorization. Indeed, any polynomial admits a unique splitting field up to a unique ring isomorphism. Then, a general answer may not exists, otherwise it would be easy to determine whether or not a polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: That's a bit over my head. I just want to know the fastest way to do it by hand.

Answer (score -1):

Read up on [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). Ignore this part of the sentence as I just need to fill up the characters.